# Why is there only one ListItem being displayed?

Tags: qt, qt5, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to recreate [this list view](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.9/qml-qtquick-listview.html#section.property-prop).  I expect it to look like this:

[image: Expected View]

But it looks like this

[image: Actual view]

This is my code:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
        anchors.fill: parent

    Component {
        id: sectionHeading
        Rectangle {
            width: parent.width
            height: childrenRect.height
            color: "lightsteelblue"
       
            Text {
                text: section
                font.bold: true
                font.pixelSize: 20
            }
        }
    }

    ListModel {
        id: animalsModel
        ListElement {
            size: "Small"
            name: "Parrot"
        }
        ListElement {
            size: "Small"
            name: "Guinea pig"
        }
        ListElement {
            size: "Medium"
            name: "Cat"
        }
        ListElement {
            size: "Medium"
            name: "Dog"
        }
        ListElement {
            size: "Large"
            name: "Elephant"
        }
    }

    ListView {
        id: view
        anchors.top: parent.top
        width: parent.width
        model: animalsModel
        delegate: Text {
            text: name
            font.pixelSize: 18
        }
        section.property: "size"
        section.criteria: ViewSection.FullString
        section.delegate: sectionHeading
    }
}
```

Why is only "Parrot" being displayed even though all the headers are displayed?

We are using Qt 5.9 on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: It's a weird side effect of not defining the height of the ListView. Setting `height: parent.height` solves it.

Comment: Wow, thanks!  If you want to put an official answer I will accept it.  Otherwise, I think I will delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a weird side effect of not defining the height of the ListView. Setting `height: parent.height` solves it.

The weird part is that it places the section headers in the right place, just not the delegates. That sounds like a bug to me. Or at least inconsistent behavior.